# Google JS API Returning "No application ids specified"

Tags: google-api, google-play-games, google-api-nodejs-client, oauth2-playground

This is a copy paste of a GitHub Issue, but due to the project contributors lack of response it is being asked here:

Hi there!

It's my first time using the Google API, and I'm trying to get my (the end user)s Google Play Games Level. I've done my fair share of research and I've been modifying the oauth sample provided by Google.

My "working" example [can be found here.](https://hastebin.com/miyituxefo.js)

After I completed basic auth and got my `access_token` from Google, I began poking directly at the source of Game (more specifically, [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/games/v1.ts#L4537-L4550)) and I started getting the following response:

```
{ 
    domain: 'global',
    reason: 'invalid',
    message: 'Invalid applicationId with value . Reason: No application ids specified.' 
}
```

I believed it was my fault, then I went to the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

I followed the most barebones method to do the request I needed:

1. Input `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games` into the box for Select and Authorize APIs
2. Give it the access it wants, and login.
3. Exchange auth code for tokens.
4. Input the following request URI `https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me`
5. Send Request
6. Same error as above.

"Strange" I thought. So I went to where I learned.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/players/get#try-it

1. Input `me` for `playerId`
2. Press execute.
3. Same error as above.

Now the issue is completely above me. Two official resources and my own poorly put together code all outputting the error. I believe the error lies within Google's flow somewhere but I'm not sure.

My next step is to await further assistance from someone more skilled than I to get this issue pointing in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I know that it's been nearly 4 years, but I now find myself in the exact same situation that you were.  The OAuth Playground, API Explorer and my app are all getting this exact error.  Do you have any recollection of what you did to resolve the issue?